# Login with Facebook integration without registering the website with facebook

Tags: facebook, button, authentication

I want to use "LOGIN with Facebook" function for the new website. I have created a page with a Facebook login.

When I am trying to get code from:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

It is asking me to create an Application.

So my question is Can I use "Login with facebook" functionality without Facebook Application integration?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.  Even when you retrieve the code you need for the Login plugin, Facebook instructs you to substitute `APP_ID` for your own.  You'll need an application if you want to retrieve data about that person when they login, for example

- email
- name
- gender
- location
- etc...

You'll have to authenticate your users with an app_id and app_secret to retrieve an access_token.  That access_token is unique per user per application.  More info on authentication is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Basically, every time you want to query Facebook's databases, with the Graph API or FQL, you do so on behalf of the user.  Facebook links these calls to applications so that they will be able to know which application has what permissions and also what they are doing with them.

Click on over to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and after you have verified your Facebook developer account you'll be able to `create a new app`